# Getting started with Java Eclipse SDK

Tags: java, eclipse

What are the steps for getting started with the Java Eclipse SDK?

Just the preliminary steps to reach the editor.

Answer (score 4):

Try the "[Eclipse and Java for Total Beginners](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=392)" material.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to [download it](http://www.eclipse.org), install it, start it up, and create a new project.